# Single XML file vs Multiple XML files: Best Solution?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript

I'm working on a Flash project that deals with multiple files. There is a main file that loads in individual SWF files as they click on different buttons. The course has dynamic text Fields that are populated via XML. So right now, my idea is to give each page it's own XML file? Would this be better suited to have one single XML file for all the pages, and the container file or multiple files?

Also, this is going to be a multilingual project. Any feedback on this would be great! Thanks!

**EDIT:** The XML files will just be storing text information to populate the text fields, and some links to load in images. Also, the loaded SWFs will never be accessed without the use of the main "container" SWF.

Comment: Will the individual swfs ever be accessed without the main swf? What type of content will be in said xml files, language text or more?

Comment: That's a good question. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only my opinion here:

Generally the text resources are not significant in size relative to the other file that get loaded, and having all pages in a single xml seems preferable to me.

For the multilingual part, I think having each languages translations in a separate xml is probably a good idea.

Kind of the flash equivalent of a single .mui resource file for each language in a traditional winforms/wpf application.

To Clarify:

- 1 Text Res file for all pages in a particular language
- Total of X Text Res files for X languages

[Flash Localization Advice](http://www.acclaro.com/newsletter/tips-flash-localization)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. This file probably has about 15-17 total pages that are loaded in, and so was just wondering if that would be too much for a single file. I definitely agree on the different XML for different languages.

Comment: @wvxvw, thanks for the reply. Well most of my images are compiled with in the SWF file. (Everything is build in Flash Pro CS5). The reason that I have the XML loading images it that the clients it so that they can just swap out certain images easily by changing only the XML.